# AnyLogic: How to display distribution of agent variables in a histogram

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to model a distribution of ages within a population of "patient" agents and visualize it in a histogram. Each patient has a variable, "PtAge" that increases by one each year - they also have an chance of dying each year and being removed from the model. So far the code is:

```
#Event, runs each year
PtAge += 1;
#PtAges is a HistogramData object
main.PtAges.add(PtAge);

if (dead)
{
    main.remove_patients(this);
}
```

I've added a histogram that displays data from the PtAges HistogramData object, but the problem is that once an age is added to the distribution it remains in the distribution permanently. How can I have a histogram that reflects the distribution of patient ages as it is currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't access the histogram data object elements and erase them individually so you will have to reset your histogram every time... so something like this:

```
ptAges.reset();
for(Patient p : patients){
    ptAges.add(p.ptAge);
}
ptAges.update(); //not sure if this is necessary for you
```